# How to loop through arrays of different lengths and run a function inside the loop

Tags: php, recursion, foreach, while-loop

I'm trying to create a function that will loop through an array of various lengths. During the loop, a function is run to see if the immediately prior item (the item at current key minus 1) matches what is in the array.
Here are two examples of arrays:

```
$terms1 = array(
    0 => 'MEL',
    1 => 'Appliances',
    2 => 'Clothes Dryers',
    3 => 'Clothes dryers - electric'
);

$terms2 = array(
    0 => 'Clothes Dryers',
    1 => 'Clothes dryers - electric'
);
```

And here is the function to be run within the loop... this function will return a value and then I will compare that to what is in the array in the immediately prior location (current key minus 1). This pulls from a db.

```
getParent($terms1[3]); //Would output the value I want to compare to $terms1[2]
```

I've tried something like this:

```
$fail = null;
foreach(array_reverse($terms1, true) as $key => $value){
    if($key > 0){
        $priorkey = $key - 1;
        if(getParent($terms1[$key]) != $terms1[$priorkey]){
            $fail = true;
        }
    }
}
return $fail;
```

I think I need a recursive function... any help or nudges in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you just trying to see if the last item entered in to the array has the same value as the current item you are about to enter? Would it be better to check the entire array for the current item?

Comment: What happened when you tried your function? What incorrect behavior did you observe?

Comment: @crush - no not exactly. getParent returns a value from my database, and I want to compare this value with the element directly prior (the value stored at current key minus 1)

Comment: @GeorgeCummins - after the `if` i echoed the value of $fail and it was to `true` 4 times.

Comment: Seems like $terms2 is not used? Could you clarify what it is for?

Comment: I think he just meant it to show that the arrays could be any size.

Comment: @ToddChaffee to give an example of another array that the function would need to work for

Comment: You should write more for what you need this. Your code should work however I assume you're running into some other issue which will turn it into some useless chunk of code pretty fast. You probably want to create some HTML out of the information in the array?

Comment: In that case, your code should work, but could be more efficient as others have already shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$prev = null;
foreach ($terms1 as $v) {
    if ($prev == getParent($v)) {
        $fail = true;
        break;
    }

    $prev = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your code doesn't work, but if you add a `break;` after `$fail = true;` it will run faster and return the same result. There's no need to check the rest after the first failure.